# Accept file upload in Type

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, api

We have a function inside the API that, right now, accepts a string and it works. I need to alter it to allow for a file to be sent instead. But all tutorials I see on the internet use const to declare the function while the original dev went with this approach below.

```
type NewFile = { fileName: string };
```

I ideally would want something like this:

```
type NewFile = { fileName: string, fileItself: file };
```

but I couldn't find resources on how to state that inside type.

I need help understanding how to do this or why it can't be done.

---

[edit] I'm putting everything I think is necessary to understand how this function works, so I can get more in depth help.

This is the entity:

```
@Entity({ name: "Files" })
export class File extends UpdatableBase {
    @Column({ type: "varchar", length: 1000, nullable: false })
    fileName: string;

    @Column({ type: "varchar", length: 50, nullable: false })
    storageProvider: string;

    @Column({ type: "bool", nullable: false })
    isMarkedForDeletion: boolean;

    downloadUrl: string;

    @ManyToOne(
        type => User,
        { lazy: true, nullable: false }
    )
    @JoinColumn({ name: "userId", referencedColumnName: "id" })
    user: Promise<User>;
}
```

This is the function "skeleton" (is there a better word?):

```
type Handler = RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, Query>;

const createNew = <TReq, TParent, TChild, TRes = DataNode.DataNode>(
    parentEntityClass: ObjectType<TParent>,
    childPropertyName: string,
    parentPropertyName: string,
    reqValidator: (body: TReq) => boolean,
    constraintSelector: (body: TReq) => string | number | Date | ObjectID,
    dataMapper: (body: TReq) => Promise<TChild>,
    responseSerializer: (
        entity: TChild,
        req?: Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, Query>
    ) => Promise<TRes>
): Handler => asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const logger = req.getLogger();
    const db = req.getDbContext();

    const reqBody = RequestUtility.getJsonAndValidate<TReq>(
        req,
        reqValidator,
        logger
    );

    const child = await dataMapper(reqBody);

    if (parentEntityClass) {
        const parent = await QueryUtility.findOneOrFail(
            db,
            parentEntityClass,
            constraintSelector(reqBody)
        );

        const childsParentWrapped: { [k: string]: any } = {};

        logger.debug(`checking if child refs parent ${JSON.stringify({
            childProps: Object.getOwnPropertyNames(child),
            prop: parentPropertyName
        })}`);

        if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(child).includes(parentPropertyName) ||
            Object.getOwnPropertyNames(child).includes(`__${parentPropertyName}__`)) {
            childsParentWrapped[parentPropertyName] = Promise.resolve(parent);

            Object.assign(child, childsParentWrapped);
        }

        if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(parent).includes(childPropertyName)) {
            await QueryUtility.addChild(db, parentEntityClass, childPropertyName, parent, child);
        } else {
            await db.manager.save(child);
        }
    } else {
        await db.manager.save(child);
    }

    const result = await responseSerializer(child, req);

    res.json(result);
});
```

This is the function itself:

```
type NewFile = { fileName: string};
type CreatedNewFileResponse = { uploadUrl: string; file: DataNode.DataNode };

export const createNewFile: Handler = createNew<NewFile, EUser, EFile, CreatedNewFileResponse>(
    EUser,
    "",
    "user",
    (body) => body.fileName ? true : false,
    (body) => 1,
    async (body) => {
        const newFile = new EFile();
        newFile.fileName = `${ShortUUID.generate()}-${body.fileName}`;
        newFile.storageProvider = "internal-storage";
        newFile.isMarkedForDeletion = false;
        newFile.user = null;

        return newFile;
    },
    async (newFile, req) => {
        const minioContext = req.getMinioContext();
        let uploadUrl = await minioContext.client.presignedUrl(
            "PUT",
            minioContext.bucket,
            newFile.fileName,
            7 * 24 * 60 * 60,
            { query: {}, headers: { host: req.hostname } }
        );
        uploadUrl = uploadUrl.replace(
            `${minioContext.config.host}:${minioContext.config.port}`,
            req.hostname
        ).replace("http:", "https:");
        return {
            uploadUrl,
            file: await DataNode.fromFile(newFile)
        };
    }
);
```

What I aim to do here: with the least amount of changes possible, turn this "type NewFile = { fileName: string }" into something that accepts a REAL file.

Comment: Maybe you mean mime-types

Comment: Use a package like [`multer`](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) or [`busboy`](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy)

Comment: I don't think so. That's the literal line in the code where it states the string the function receives. I need it to take a file instead (jpg, mp4, mp3, whatever it is). It's a function to insert a new file on the API; that function when triggered by the API call creates a new entry in the database with a URL to the file. The file is deposited on a MinIO server. The URL points there. As of now, there's no file being uploaded but the MinIO context is being given (ie: I get a URL on the database with the fileName, but it leads nowhere because there's no file).